# How to load a database with more than a million rows into pivot table cache?

Tags: excel, database, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that shows the sales data of the company since 2019, and I need to update it with June's information. However, the problem is that Excel cannot handle adding 200,000 rows to the 1,046,984 in my current database. How can I do this without using Access? Should I use a CSV file instead?

Comment: It sounds like you are (ab)using Excel as a database. Please don't do that.

Comment: Actually it is my only resource. So why don't?

Comment: Excel performs quite horribly as a database.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of that this works within excel is by leveraging PowerPivot (see [here](https://chandoo.org/wp/more-than-million-rows-in-excel/)).

Comment: One more thing: Since Excel performs **extremely poor** with large amounts of data, I would highly recommend using SQL or Access or even R, Python, etc. All of those options are much faster and can hold more data.